# Не работает генерация пароля

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Столкнулся с проблемой при написании сайта, а именно - не работает генерация пароля. Сама суть задачи в чем - есть поле для ввода пароля, а рядом "Сгенерировать", при нажатии на которое в поле ввода пароля вставляется сгенерированный пароль. Собственно, вот сам кусочек с полем для пароля:

```
<li>
   <label for="">Пароль</label>
   <span class="star">*</span>
   <input type="text" name="reg_pass" id="reg_pass">
   <span id="genpass">Сгенерировать</span>
</li>
```

Написал вот такой вот скрипт в отдельном файле на php для генерации пароля:

```
    <?php
    $number = 7;

    $arr = array('a','b','c','d','e','f',

                 'g','h','i','j','k','l',

                 'm','n','o','p','r','s',

                 't','u','v','x','y','z',

                 '1','2','3','4','5','6',

                 '7','8','9','0');

    // Генерируем пароль

    $pass = "";

    for($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++)

    {

      // Вычисляем случайный индекс массива

      $index = rand(0, count($arr) - 1);

      $pass .= $arr[$index];

    }


  echo $pass;
?>
```

А это уже ajax-функция, которая обрабатывает "Сгенерировать" и должна сразу выводить сгенерированный пароль в input, однако, увы, почему-то не работает... Располагается функция в отдельном файле, где есть еще и другие функции, которые успешно работают. Вот её код:

```
$('#genpass').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/functions/genpass.php",
  dataType: "html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
  $('#reg_pass').val(data);
  }
});

});
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, почему функция не работает...

Comment: Не по теме вопроса: генерирование паролей на сервере вызовет сомнения в безопасности у пользователей, а 7 символов для пароля слишком мало

Comment: По теме вопроса: ошибка-то какая-нибудь в консоли или где-то ещё печатается?

Comment: @andreymal нет, ошибку не наблюдаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Генерируйте пароль на клиентской строне, зачем зря сервер мучать?

```
function generatePassword(length = 8){
    let alphabet = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm';
    let pass = '';
    while(length--)
        pass += alphabet[~~(Math.random()*alphabet.length)];
    return pass;
}
```

**UP:**

Как это прикрутить:

```
$('#genpass').click(() => {
 $('#reg_pass').val(generatePassword());
});
```

Comment: изучил ваш скрипт) закинул его в директорию js а в своём ajax-скрипте вместо url: "/functions/genpass.php" указал url: "/js/genpassword.js", однако при нажатии "Сгенерировать" мне в поле ввода пароля выдаёт текст "function generatePassword(length = 7){    let alphabet = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm';    let pass = '';    while(length--)        pass += alphabet[~~(Math.random()*alphabet.length)];    return pass;}"

то есть - содержимое скрипта) где-то я туплю...

Comment: @Dremjke обновил ответ

Comment: не сочтите за тупость, но не совсем понял, как правильно "прикрутить"... вместо моей ajax-функции вставить?

Comment: Ну да. Зачем вам отсылать лишний раз запрос на сервер, если всё то же самое можно сделать на клиенте

Comment: всё, уже разобрался полностью с кодом, спасибо вам большое!)

Comment: А всё-таки это не является ответом на вопрос)

Comment: @andreymal Предложите свой ответ. Есть вероятность, что кому то он будет полезен

Answer (score 1):

возвращай json из скрипта:

```
$ans= [
   'pass' => $pass,
];
return json_encode($ans)
```

и на клиенте получай json:

```
$('#genpass').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
       url: "/functions/genpass.php",
       cache: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data.pass) {
           $('#reg_pass').val(data.pass);
       },
       error: function() {
           alert('Error'); 
       }
   });

 });
```

Comment: И вам спасибо, этот метод тоже пригодится!